# Sensor data is written multiple times when using Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sensors

I write an app to save sensors data into a file. Goal is to save IMU datas with 100 Hz.
I use Asynctask for the storage part. All seems well; but when i saw values in file, there's a many data written many times. Do you have any ideas:

[image]

```
    @Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    //timestamp = (new Date()).getTime() + (event.timestamp - System.nanoTime()) / 1000000L;
    timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    // Handle accelerometer reading
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        bufferData[0] = event.values[0];
        bufferData[1] = event.values[1];
        bufferData[2] = event.values[2];

    }
    // Handle a gyro reading
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {

        bufferData[3] = event.values[0];
        bufferData[4] = event.values[1];
        bufferData[5] = event.values[2];
    }

       save_IMU save_imu = new save_IMU();
        save_imu.execute(); 

}
```

Comment: Add your asynctask code, please.

Comment: class save_IMU extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer ,Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (MainActivity.is_recording) {
                // Create folder name
                store_data();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean saved) {
        }
    };

Comment: here mu code in Asynctask task , sorry for deranged code, i don't know how to put them clearly.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is not good choice for your problem.

You'r asynctask reads shared data from the bufferData array which is overiden each time sensor value changes. The AsyncTask is not started in the moment you call execute method. It's put into a queue and than it is waiting for free thread to be executed. So it can take same time before it'll run. Writing to the storage can be slower than you need so the queue will fill up and more tasks can be run between two onSensorChanged calls. Than they can write multiple equal rows as you see.

My suggestion:

1. Create queue / buffer for measured values. Add new items in onSensorChanged
2. Use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to periodically (e.g. each 250ms) check buffer and write items to disk (more at on run). If you don't want to experiment with handlers it can be also done with AsyncTask.

Comment: can you precise how to use handler to send bufferdata, i have searched about that, but not really understand how to apply in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`bufferData` should be a local variable of `onSensorChanged()` function.

You should transfer the buffer to the asynctask with `new save_IMU(bufferData );`.